# How to use operators between table grid column and datetime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a grid on my form with column `ExpirationDate`. Above the grid I have two check boxes, `active` and `inactive`.

When I click active check box I want that my grid shows me only rows with expiration date greater or equal than today date.

When I set condition like this:

```
private string OR(string filter)
{
    if (filter != "")
        return "OR";

    return "";
}

private void chbFilter_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter = "";
    if (chbAktivan.Checked)
        filter += ExpirationDate >= DateTime.Today;
    if (chbNeaktivan.Checked)
    {
        filter += OR(filter);
        filter += ExpirationDate < DateTime.Today;
    }

    bsFilter.Filter = filter;
}
```

Please, focus just on my code `filter += ExpirationDate >= DateTime.Today`.

The error is:

> Error 196 Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' and
>   'System.DateTime'

Any idea?

Comment: not sure why you want to concat string `filter` with a result of expression. i think it should be smth like `filter += String.Format(" ExpirationDate >= '{0}' ", DateTime.Today);`

Comment: Yeah, your code is working! Tnx man... Please, just type code like others so I can accept answer, because I cant do that now...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently you are trying to concat string `filter` with a result of expression. 
()

but filter expression for bindingSource should be provided in text format

```
filter += String.Format(" ExpirationDate >= '{0}' ", DateTime.Today);
...
filter += String.Format(" ExpirationDate < '{0}' ", DateTime.Today);
```

if i remember correct DateTime values should be written inside `' '`

Answer (score 2):

Just Try This :

```
private void chbFilter_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter = "";
    if (chbAktivan.Checked)
        filter += "ExpirationDate >= '{0}'," + DateTime.Today;
    if (chbNeaktivan.Checked)
    {
        filter += OR(filter);
        filter += "ExpirationDate < '{0}'," + DateTime.Today;
    }

    bs.Filter = string.Format(filter);
}
```

Comment: It won't work without '{0}' .  Just need to add this. Edit your code please, so I can say that is done.:)

" ExpirationDate >= '{0}' ", DateTime.Today

Comment: Done, hi i have also put answer on your ' How to use multiple event handler text_changed in C#? ' question please check.

Comment: Yeah, I checked now, it was correct too! :) Unfortunatelly, i don't have enough reputation to vote on answers, I can only check it. When somebody give right answer first, i checked it. Some guy above answered correctly before you, but I have to thank you on your support dude! :)

Comment: it's ok. i want to just confirmation is it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
filter += "ExpirationDate >= " + DateTime.Today;
```